# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

That's my controller:

```
public function manageCategory() {  
    $categories = Category::all(); 

    return view('admin.category.manageCategory',['categories'=>'$categories']); 
}
```

My blade file:

```
@section ('content')    
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        {{$category->categoryDescription}}
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

when I save and refresh the page I get an error--->

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\larashop\resources\views\admin\category\manageCategory.blade.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the variable `$categories` to the view, but you are passing the string `'$categories'`.

So change this `['categories'=>'$categories']` to `['categories' => $categories]`

Comment: Or use `compact('categories')` instead. It is the equivalent to `['categories' => $categories]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public function manageCategory() {  
    $categories = Category::all(); 
    return view('admin.category.manageCategory')
          ->with(['categories'=>$categories]); 
}
```

and you can use this compact function:

```
public function manageCategory() {  
        $categories = Category::all(); 
        return view('admin.category.manageCategory',compact('categories')); 
    }
```